# What does "drink" refer to?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), Scoresby extracted Amrita from Tulkun brain:

> Scoresby: Amrita is what's paying for everything here
> on Pandora now. Even your research. Ain't that right, Dr. G?
>
> Dr. G: It's why I **drink**.

What does "drink" refer to? Is it referred to alcoholic beverages
or Amrita itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance he appears to be referring to alcohol. He's aware that without the (objectively unpleasant) harvesting of amrita, he wouldn't be able to do the research work that he considers to be vital.

This contradiction is 'driving him to drink'

> To be so unpleasant as to impel one to drink alcohol to forget about it.
>
> <sub><sup>https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drive+him+to+drink</sup></sub>